# Laravel access name of foreign key in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

Inquries table contains client_id as a foreign key, I want to Access ist Name in my view.
The clients table has a name column.

I tried following to Show the Name in my view but it did not work.

```
@foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
    <td>{{ $inquiryValue->client_id }}</td> // works
    <td>{{ $inquiryValue->client_id->name }}</td> // does not work
@endforeach
```

Client Model

```
public function inquiry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
}
```

Inquiry

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation examples on relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client_id` is just the id of the client. Since you have a relation in place, you should refer to that instead: `{{ $inquiryValue->client->name }}`

Comment: We were all beginners at one point. This asker obviously tried to do something themself and posted the relevant info in the question.

Comment: Well of course, but he failed and came for help to big moma (SO). Answer to his question can be **easily** found in Laravel's documentation. Obviously has no clue how to debug the thing (`dd()`, or using tinker etc...) I bet one week later OP will come to SO again "it does not work" (with similar question) (I don't bet I am worried).

Comment: Then let them. SO is not only for people who are experts and stumbled into a really difficult scenario. I don't mind answering really simple questions as long as the asker has at least tried to put a little effort into it. I'm here to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
@foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
    <td>{{ $inquiryValue->client_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $inquiryValue->client->name }}</td> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ $inquiryValue->name }}
```

Also you may check variables from below code

```
dd(get_defined_vars())
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This..

**Client Model**

```
public function inquiries()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
  }
```

**Inquiry Model**

```
public function client()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
  }
```

**View**

```
@foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
  <td>{{ $inquiryValue->client_id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $inquiryValue->client->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What did you change and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: @JJJ I changed nothing just mentioned the foreign key in the inquiry model and how to show this thing in a view file. that's it. I hope this will help for him.